# NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n)[c -> n -> J -> J -> J]

Tags: angular, obfuscation

I'm working on old angular project developed by ex-colleague an I'm trying to debug it. However, during runtime, I encounter the following error:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n)[c -> n -> J -> J -> J]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for J!
  at Qd.get (main.js:1:1159201)
  at gy.get (main.js:1:1160554)
  at gy.get (main.js:1:1160554)
  at gy.get (main.js:1:1160554)
  at Rv (main.js:1:1131811)
  at Object.Ir (main.js:1:1131912)
  at n.ɵfac [as factory] (main.js:1:194040)
  at gy.hydrate (main.js:1:1162531)
  at gy.get (main.js:1:1160506)
  at Rv (main.js:1:1131811)
```

It appears that the code is obfuscated.

Is it possible to disable obfuscation?

Comment: This obfuscated code means, that the Angular project has been compiled in production mode. To see the unobfuscated code, you could try to start it in development mode.

Comment: (check that `optimisation` is `false` in `angular.json`)

Comment: I set optimization to false but this didn't help

Answer (score 0):

All the recommendations I found were to set `optimization` flag to `false`. But this didn't work; in debug mode application remained obfuscated. It was only when I ran `ng serve --configuration production` that I finally received the unobfuscated error

Comment: well then you are making a mistake, now you turned your production config into  development settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the pipes you use to both the declarations and providers sections of the module. You should also make sure that your services are in the providers section.